# how do I prove n^3.5 is not O(n^3)

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, big-o

How do I prove n^3.5 is not O(n^3)?

I am doing this for my algorithm class.

It says I need to prove it using proof by Contradiction!

Comment: The calculation of `n^3.5` is `O(1)` ...

Comment: Use the definition of big-O notation.

Comment: As the first step, take the definition of f(n) = O(g(n)) and write it for f(n)=n^3.5 and g(n)=n^3. After that, fix the constant C and find n=n(C) for which what you wrote does not hold.

Comment: @cricket_007 that's pretty nice, but not even close to a solution. `n^3.5 ?= O(n^3)` isn't asking for the runtime-complexity of a method to calculate the value, but the asymptotic behavior of an implied function `f(n) = n^3.5`, which is something entirely different.

Comment: @Paul I assume the question was rather asking about `O(n^3.5)`

Comment: @cricket_007 No, the question is good as it is. The _function_ n^3.5 does not belong to the _class_ O(n^3).

Comment: @cricket_007 so do I, but why should `O(n^3.5)` be `O(1)`? AFAIK `n^3.5 = n^3 * sqrt(n)`, which is definitely not a constant.

Comment: There's a formal definition of [BigO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Formal_definition) given on wikipedia. Proving that `n^3.5` doesn't belong to `O(n^3)` shouldn't be too hard using that formula. The rest of just assuming that factors exist such that that formula is satisfied and proving that they don't exist.

Comment: @Paul My point was that for any value N, say `10000`, calculation of `1000^3.5` is computationally less than iterating `10000` elements from a list in `O(N)`, linear time.

Comment: If something is _just too obvious_, try _proof by contradiction_.

Comment: @cricket_007 the function to **calculate** `n^3.5` is indeed `O(1)` (implementation specific, but that's not the main-problem here). But that's fundamentally different from both the complexity-class `O(n^3.5)`, which is the complexity-class of functions with asymptotic growth smaller than `n^3.5` and `n^3.5` itself, which a mathematical function. You mix up the asymptotic complexity of an algorithm, which is modeled by a function to depict the number of iterations required and a function itself.

Comment: @Paul And this is why the question should be worded better. I know what I meant, and you know what you mean, so let's leave it at that

Answer (score 6):

Let us use [the definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) of big O.

f(n) = O(g(n)) means that there exists a constant C and a value n<sub>0</sub> such that for every n > n<sub>0</sub>, |f(n)| <= C |g(n)|.

We want to prove that for f(n) = n<sup>3.5</sup> and g(n) = n<sup>3</sup> by contradiction.
So, assume that there exists such constant C that |n<sup>3.5</sup>| <= C |n<sup>3</sup>| holds.
Sure, it's false, and here's why: take, for example, n = C<sup>10</sup>, and see that |C<sup>35</sup>| <= C |C<sup>30</sup>|, which is the same as to say that C<sup>35</sup> <= C<sup>31</sup>.
And that's obviously false for any C > 1.
For any larger n (recall we need n > n<sub>0</sub>), this also obviously does not hold.